# Is "volumn" a correct word? Was it ever one?

Tags: etymology, orthography, is-it-a-word, language-evolution, non-standard

I sometimes see the word *volumn*, and I'm not sure if it's simply a spelling error for *volume*. I am wondering if it's actually correct. Possible angles to consider:

- Is *volumn* used frequently enough that it's become a valid alternative spelling? In other words, is it widely understood?
- Is *volumn* included in dictionaries? I can't find it in any online dictionary, but perhaps it could be found in a historical, dialectal, technical, or print one?
- Is it defensible from an etymological perspective?
- Was it once more common?
- Does it just mean 'volume,' or does it have a separate meaning?

Comment: If you can't find it in any dictionary, then there is no justification to use it and you can safely assume it's a mistake.

Comment: 3,220,000 results for *volumn* on GoogleSearch; 27,600 results for GoogleBooks.

Comment: @Kris: Did you find any instances among those millions (or thousands) of search results that would lead you to believe this is a correct word for the 21st century? If so, I'd like to know. I think it's an antiquated spelling at best. Raw totals don't tell the full answer.

Comment: @JR *Antiquated* is a valid answer. You should have posted that as an answer.

Comment: To post an answer, please vote to re-open. Invalid edits will be rolled back.

Comment: Why is the accepted answer for this question from someone who has clearly done little research? Volumn it is a rare and archaic, British spelling of Volume. It is used in other countries outside of the United States as well. This makes it correct in global English even if it is not correct in American English, although interestingly it can also be found in published American books:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=volumn&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvolumn%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Kris **"3,220,000 results for volumn on GoogleSearch;"** This claim is so wildly inaccurate that it is laughable. A trip to the bottom of the search page will show  **"In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 202 already displayed."** See how different 3,220,000 is from 202? These are OCR errors.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on OCR errors.

Comment: This could be an interesting question. Instances of _volumn_ in English appear at least as early as 1550 (in William Wats's translation of St. Augustine's _Confessions_), and multiple instances appear in more recent Google Books search results, such as [these (more than 300) for the period 1915–1985](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22volumn%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1915,cd_max:1985&lr=lang_en). Although some may be typographical errors, many appear to be intentional (given that they appear multiple times), perhaps influenced by the spelling of _column_. I would reopen this question.

Comment: I should note that the "more than 300" language in my previous note refers to matches for published works that include at least one instance of _volumn_, not to works that include two or more instances—although a fair number of them do contain multiple marches.

Comment: I voted to reopen because questions are closed for very basic research, eg the main online dictionaries. But a good question would include deeper research. You can easily find older dictionaries online like the first edition of the OED. And can search Google Books and read some results. But that's not grounds for closure.

Answer (score 5):

I've never heard of "volumn," and a few searches turn up nothing except several people who claim to have seen this word in use. On [Newsgorilla](http://newsgorilla.blogspot.com/2003_04_20_newsgorilla_archive.html) a couple of researchers took on the task of finding it in the OED, but they couldn't. I think it's safe to say **not a proper word**.

It's quite possible for Google books to return instances of a word that are really typos or scanning errors, like this:

[image: Google Books title: "Written Education Induced Neurosis: A True Story Volumn XIV"; In text: "Volume XIV"]

although sometimes the [scanned book](http://books.google.com/books?id=7fM6AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA394&dq=volumn&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6Gg4Uf3lC4n32wW574GYCg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwATgo#v=onepage&q=volumn&f=false) unmistakeably contains the word in question:

[image: One page with "Volumn both cylinders" and three instances of "volumn cylinders"]

That latter example, though, was published in 1906. If *volumn* was once an acceptable alternate spelling of *volume*, it appears to have gone out of vogue, to the point where the dictionary editors don't want to acknowledge it in current editions.

Comment: An example: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39902/624014